# https caching of resources used by main php script, NOT the script itself

Tags: php, caching, https, header, http-headers

I'm a little confused here. I read some of the earlier questions on https caching but I didnt get a clear answer.

I've got a script sitting on: https://www.example.com/main.php

It generates an html page that refers to images/css/js resources sitting (relatively) at:
/css /javascript /images /a/b/img2

How do I enable caching for these resources?? I have access to modifying the header output of the main.php script.

---

Edit: Solution as below:

```
#Set a far expiration date for components
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
  <filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js)$">
       ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 months"
   </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>

#add ETag for components
FileETag MTime Size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Apache web server you probably need a .htaccess file to enter caching information about your components.

In the .htaccess file:

```
#Set a far expiration date for components
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
  <filesmatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$">
       ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
   </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>

#add ETag for components
FileETag MTime Size
```

Access to header output of the main.php script can only modify caching for your main script, not the components.

Comment: Hi Mauris, I'm reading up on mod_expires and it looks like it would work wonderfully! But I'm confused with the filesmatch command on jpg|gif|png - why have you used that?

Comment: I only want my components to be cached, not my php script as the content might be dynamic.

Comment: Sorry for being an ass here and pursuing this point (BTW - your solution works!)... But isnt jpg|gif|png redundant? We're already specifying it in the ExpiresByType entry, no?

Comment: well you can say that again =D - can't remember why I did that. Copied from an old project.

Comment: oh yes, the ExpiresByType only apply to images, you still have css and js in the filesmatch

Comment: Great! Thanks Mauris - I've put up the adapted version in my original post itself. I think that would work without issue!
Thanks!

Comment: if it works, give the answer a tick so that others know the answer =)

Comment: Works great! Sorry for not ticking it earlier!